# Errors in Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, web

I created a Laravel project using this command `composer create command-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` then I opened the project in Netbeans but the project contains errors.

One of the errors is in `class_with_method_that_declares_anonymous_class`

```php
$o = new class {
    public function foo() {} 
};
```

Another mistake is in `ReportSpecificationstarts`, among others.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you are using laravel master installation, which requires PHP >= 5.5.9.
this class keyword is supported only in PHP >= 5.5.9, and your net beans is not supporting it as it is using older version of PHP.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1 with PHP 5.6 and the errors still appears